# Conventional Interface, Pipline

Tags: python

hello guys i have mission in my collage
this is output of section 1:

> courses = (('a', [81, 78, 57]), ('b', [95, 98]), ('c', [75, 45]),
> ('d', [58]))
>
> print(avg_grades(courses))
>
> (('a', 72.0), ('b', 96.5),('c', 60.0), ('d', 58.0))

**"The Mission is"**

Write function add_factors that receives

- a. list of couples - courses with a grade (as in the output of
  section 1).
- b. list
  of Couples - Courses and Factor for certain
  courses for which a factor needs to be calculated.

The function returns the list of courses with updated scores after the factor.

**The loops in the above question must not be used.**

**Running example:**

> courses = (('a', [81, 78, 57]), ('b', [95, 98]), ('c', [75, 45]),
> ('d', [58]))
>
> factors = (('c', 15), ('a', 20))
>
> print(add_factors(avg_grades(courses), factors))
>
> (('a', 92.0), ('b', 96.5), ('c', 75.0), ('d', 58.0))

This my code but i dont know how to bulid the add_factors:

```
# --------------Conventional Interface, Pipline-------------------
from functools import reduce

def avg_course(course):
    name_grade = list(course)
    name_grade[1] = reduce(add,name_grade[1])/len(name_grade[1])
    return tuple(name_grade)

def avg_grades(courses):
    return tuple(map(avg_course,list(courses)))


def add_factors(courses,factors):
    lst_courses = list(map(lambda x:list(x),courses))
    lst_factor = list(map(lambda x:list(x),factors))


courses = (('a', [81, 78, 57]), ('b', [95, 98]), ('c', [75, 45]), ('d', [58]))
factors = (('c', 15), ('a', 20))

print(avg_grades(courses))
```

Comment: maybe first create function which gets two object - curse and factor ie. `('a', [81, 78, 57])`  `('c', 15)` and calcuate what you need if both have the same char - and later you can use it with `map()` or `reduce()` to run it without `for`-loop

Comment: BTW: instead of `map(lambda x:list(x), ...)` you could write `map(list, ...)`